# Random numbers from an irregular range C

Tags: arrays, random, numbers

Hello how would I get numbers randomly from a group of specific numbers using arrays in C? Say, I wanted to generate 50 numbers from a set of these numbers:

```
52 67 80 87 90 95
```

Comment: I think he doesnt want an actual range, he wants an arbitrary range. This can only be accomplished by predefined arrays.

Comment: The solution should be put in an Answer, not in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make an array A of size n to store arbitrary set eg, { 52, 67, 80, 87, 90, 95 }
2. save the length l of the fixed array eg, 6
3. make a random number r from 0 to length exclusive
4. item = A[r] where r = rand % l